# how to change a macro variable to a simple data

Tags: sql, sas

I have this tiny part from a macro variable that creates a macro variable

```
data dico&&pays&l ; set dico&&pays&l ;
call symput("nvar&&pays&l",trim(left(_n_))) ;
run;
```

I want to use the info to do an update on the column of a table like below

```
proc sql;
create table toto (col1 varchar(8));
update toto set col1="nvar&&pays&l";
quit;
```

Issue is the table `toto` is not updated ...

Why?

Comment: If `toto` exists and has some records, it will be updated assuming your macro variables are properly defined.  In the above example it won't be, because it has no rows, so nothing to update.

Comment: Hi Joe, so easy... arggh. I feel stupid... Thank you.

Comment: @Joe Don't forget to convert that into an answer!

Comment: Hmm, wasn't sure if this really was a proper answer or just a close-OT-bug, but I guess it's marginally useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty table cannot be updated, because it has no rows to update; `update` does not create rows.  Thus,

```
proc sql;
create table toto (col1 varchar(8));
update toto set col1="nvar&&pays&l";
quit;
```

Does not update any rows because `toto` is empty.  If you run the `update` on a dataset that exists, it will work.